# Select rows from last existing 12 months

Tags: mysql

There's a `DATETIME` column called `time`. How could I select all rows that fall within the last **existing** 12 months (**NOT within the last year from today**)? Not every month might have a row, and months may have more than one row.

For example, out of this table (`ORDER BY time DESC`), rows with ids 2 to 17 would be selected.

```
id    time
--    ----
17    2015-04-01
16    2015-04-01
15    2015-03-01
14    2015-02-01
13    2015-01-01
12    2014-12-01
11    2014-11-01
10    2014-10-01
 9    2013-12-01
 8    2013-11-01
 7    2013-10-01
 6    2013-09-01
 5    2013-09-01
 4    2013-09-01
 3    2013-09-01
 2    2013-08-01
 1    2013-07-01
```

Another way to put this:

Take the table above and group by month/year, so we get:

```
2015-04
2015-03
2015-02
2015-01
2014-12
2014-11
2014-10
2013-12
2013-11
2013-10
2013-09
2013-08
2013-07
```

Now take the 12 most recent months from this list, which is everything except 2013-07.

```
2015-04
2015-03
2015-02
2015-01
2014-12
2014-11
2014-10
2013-12
2013-11
2013-10
2013-09
2013-08
```

And select everything from those months.

I guess I could do this with multiple queries or subqueries but is there another way to do this?

Comment: You should explain this a bit more, it's not particularly clear what you're trying to do from this example

Comment: Start with: SELECT DISTINCT time FROM table ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 12

Answer (score 0):

If your time field is only month-precision, you could do it with a pretty simple subselect:

```
SELECT * FROM Table t1
WHERE time IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT time FROM Table t2 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 12
)
```

If your timestamps are full-precision, you could do the same thing, but you'd need to do some date manipulation to round the dates to the month for comparison.